# Why is my code inaccurate when using list comprehension?

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I am learning python and was attempting the following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od1OT.png). This is the code I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x**3-3*x**2-5.5*x+25

x = np.linspace(-3,5,10000)

for i in x:
    if f(i)>f(i-1) and f(i)>f(i+1):
        max=i
    if f(i)<f(i-1) and f(i)<f(i+1):
        min=i
print('Coordinates for maxima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(max,f(max)))
print('Coordinates for minima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(min,f(min)))
```

However, the output is overshooting the answer I want so I messed around with it and when I used the following loop it worked perfectly:

```
for i in range(1,len(x)-1):
    if f(x[i])>f(x[i-1]) and f(x[i])>f(x[i+1]):
        max=x[i]
    if f(x[i])<f(x[i-1]) and f(x[i])<f(x[i+1]):
        min=x[i]
```

So my question is why does the second loop work better than the first? I thought both methods would have the same output.

Comment: Your code is not doing the same. In your second code you increment/decrement the index, in your first code the value.

Comment: Also, your second version is skipping the first element in `x`.

Comment: @jasonharper - And the last element. Otherwise it would yield a `index out of bounds` error.

Comment: There is no list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

First, you aren't using list comprehensions. Second, the loop expressions

```py
for i in x:
    if f(i)>f(i-1)...
```

and

```py
for i in range(1,len(x)-1):
    if f(x[i])>f(x[i-1]) ...
```

mean different things.

First, the first one loops over *all* the elements of `x`, while the second loops over *almost* all the elements of `x`, but excludes the first and last elements.

Second, `f(i-1)` (where `i` is an element of `x`) and `f(x[i-1])` (where `i` is an index) mean different things. You seem to think that `f(i-1)` in the first loop is equivalent to `f(x[i-1])` in the second loop, when it's really equivalent to `f(x[i] - 1)` instead. **Notice where the `-1` is with respect to the bracket `]`.**

Answer (score 0):

Rather than incrementing or decrementing i with 1, if you would have used gap, which is the difference between adjacent elements of array x, then this code will equivalent to the code below (ignoring boundary conditions, -3 & 5). Check the code below for reference.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x**3-3*x**2-5.5*x+25

x = np.linspace(-3,5,10000)
gap = x[1] - x[0]

for i in x:
    if f(i)>f(i-gap) and f(i)>f(i+gap):
        max=i
    if f(i)<f(i-gap) and f(i)<f(i+gap):
        min=i
print('Coordinates for maxima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(max,f(max)))
print('Coordinates for minima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(min,f(min)))
```

Comment: Well, for this particular input data. Not in general.

Comment: Your solution works for evenly spaced data, but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your bounds are not the same. But moreover, with your correct loop, you are evaluating adjacent abscissa values given by your `linespace` arguments (approximately 8/10000). With your incorrect loop, you are evaluating points that are separated by abscissa values of plus and minus 1.

If we ignore the first problem, though algorithmically incorrect, but doesn't matter in this example only because there are no local minima at -3 or 5:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x**3-3*x**2-5.5*x+25

x = list(np.linspace(-3,5,10000))
delta = 8/10000 #

for i in x:
    if f(i)>f(i-delta) and f(i)>f(i+delta):
        max=i
    if f(i)<f(i-delta) and f(i)<f(i+delta):
        min=i
print('Coordinates for maxima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(max,f(max)))
print('Coordinates for minima: ({:.3f},{:.3f})'.format(min,f(min)))
```

Comment: This is almost the same as Alok Nayak's answer, but with the additional downside that the gap between `x[0]` and `x[1]` is hardcoded instead of calculated from `x`.

Comment: @jmramsey You are of course, correct. But the question the OP posed was why his one method produced the wrong results. The answer was that he was not looking at adjacent abscissa values, which is really the main point. And my `delta`  value is actually just an excellent approximation, which works in this case. But this code (as is  the code Alok posted) is still wrong because the boundary conditions are still wrong and is not meant to be usable anyway as is. It was just shown as proof of where the OP went wrong.